# Django get_media_prefix with trailing slash to Javascript url

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm having problems getting my MEDIA_URL (which is something like https://example.com/media/) to use in Javascript. I can use the get_media_prefix template tag as

```
var media_prefix = {% get_media_prefix %};
```

to fetch my MEDIA_URL but it gives me an unexpected token ':' error, which makes sense because the URL has a ':' after the https part. I tried converting it to a String with

```
var media_prefix = String({% get_media_prefix %});
```

but then the error is the String function does not see the closing ')' as it is escaped by the trailing slash in the URL. Same problem if I try

```
var media_prefix = new URL({% get_media_prefix %});
```

How can I resolve my trailing slash problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick but just a heads up this can lead to security issues and injection attacks

```
var media_prefix = "{% get_media_prefix %}";
```